# Order by field that may be null

Tags: sql, django

I have the following query:

```
tasks = tasks.order_by('order_item__due_date', 'title__name')
```

However, `order_item` may be NULL, in which case the above query will be invalid (because NULL object doesn't have a due_date).

In this case, how would I do the following:

```
tasks = tasks.order_by('order_item__due_date' if order_item, 'title_name')
```

Comment: What type of DB? Oracle? if so, read about NVL() or NVL2(). The order by clause may then look something like this ORDER BY NVL(order_item,order_item__due_date)

Comment: Have you tried that? What is the error? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3):

What is the error? If it ain't broke, don't fix it. ;)

You can:

1. select all tasks without order_item and sort them by title.
2. select all tasks with order_item and sort them by order_item__due_date.
3. join the two querysets.

Like this:

```
tasks = Tasks.objects.all() 
objects_by_title = tasks.objects.filter(order_item__isnull=True).order_by('title')
objects_by_due_date = tasks.objects.filter(order_item__isnull=False).order_by('order_item__due_date')
queryset = objects_by_title | objects_by_due_date
```

**UPDATE:**

Your code will work fine even if order_item is Null.

```
tasks = tasks.order_by('order_item__due_date', 'title__name')
```

Accessing is something else. This will print due_dates till it reaches a obj without order_item, than it'll raise AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'due_date'.

```
for obj in tasks: 
    print obj.order_item.due_date
```